# Unity photon plugin

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

I have created a multiplier card game using photon plugin in unity,But i stuck in displaying one user data to other,How to display one user data to other in unity using photon can anyone please help

Answer (score 1):

How many player will be in your game? if just two, you can use photonView.IsMine like

```
if(photonView.IsMine){
 //if you want you can change your color here
 }else{
 //if you want you can change others player' color here
 }
```